# DatePicker not displaying properly in Bootstrap ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a date picker in my form and it is not displaying properly in any browser

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateJoined, new { @class = "datepicker" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateJoined)
</div>
```

I have added jquery UI and added Javascript like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers
    });
</script>
```

And this is how it is displaying in UI:

[image]

Comment: Have you included the relevant .css files?

Comment: could u please tell me the necessary css for this datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/locisula/1/edit)

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

You need to include following files

```
//css file jQuery UI
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

//jQuery file js reference.
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

//jQuery UI js reference.
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dead link. Doesn't add value to this question at all.

Comment: How is it dead? Its a working demo for datepicker. As the problem was just with the css files.

Comment: Link working now, but you should at least add some context from the page because it could go down permenently. adding the +1 back.

Answer (score 0):

In the App_Start/Bundle.config

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));
```